# Discard edit confirmation even when editing has been stopped

Tags: bug, edits

In a certain case, the user will be asked to confirm if he/she wishes to leave the page, due to editing a post, even when he/she has stopped editing.

To reproduce:

1. Start editing a post (I've only experienced this with a question)
2. Another user finishes editing the post before you and the message "This post has been edited" appears
3. Clicking on the message bar will take you out of editing mode and will show you the updated post from the other user's edits
4. Trying to navigate away from the page will then ask for your confirmation

Comment: I don't doubt that this can happen, but seems like an edge case to me. How often does this happen to you? I am much more frustrated by some other little usability bugs on the site and think that just confirming you want to leave the page is an acceptable workaround for this scenario. (I'd rather have the devs work on more important issues.)

Comment: I've only encountered this bug once and, I agree, it does seem a bit nit-picky.  I did want there to be record of though, in case anyone else ran into it.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've hit this bug twice in one week.  I guess my edits take too long...

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208345/is-there-a-way-to-save-an-edit-or-be-advised-that-the-post-we-are-editing-is-a