# Mid-edit change notification doesn't clear "dirty" flag

Tags: bug, notifications, inline-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Discard edit confirmation even when editing has been stopped](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138543/discard-edit-confirmation-even-when-editing-has-been-stopped)

While in the middle of a question edit and another user edits the question, you get a notification notifying you that there are changes since you entered edit mode. This is fine, and if you click it you're displayed the new changes. However, clicking it (and thus escaping the edit mode) doesn't clear the "dirty" flag, making SO prompt you when you go to leave the page.

To see what I mean:

1. Open a question that needs editing.
2. Click *edit* and begin your revisions.
3. Wait for another user to edit and save changes while you're still editing
   *The gray bar should now show up letting you know there are changes*
4. Click the bar.
   *You'll now leave edit mode and be dumped on the question showing the newest changes*
5. Click any link on the page

This is where the typical *This page is asking if you're sure you want to leave* dialog appears (when it shouldn't--we're no longer in edit mode). My assumption is the "dirty flag" isn't reset when SO re-populates the page with the revised content (but instead just hidden and back-populated with AJAX).

Just thought I'd mention it.

Comment: @TimStone: It's funny, i tried searching as many keywords as possible but didn't locate that post. Maybe I'm just tired, but thanks for the reference. ;-)

Comment: There's a running joke that all Meta posts are piped directly into my brain, so there's no shame in me magically coming along with a duplicate link for your post, heh. ;)

Comment: At the very least maybe it'll bring more attention to your original post. :-)

Comment: @TimStone I think you misunderstand... **nobody is joking when they say MSO feeds directly into your brain** :-)