# Is it worth adding an "Upload Image" button to the mobile versions of the sites and chat?

Tags: feature-request, mobile-web, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Add an Image Upload button to the Mobile Site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153551/add-an-image-upload-button-to-the-mobile-site)

A number of features and UI elements are not included in the mobile versions of our sites.  In some cases, we simply can't fit everything in a moderately usable interface, but in others, the action simply wasn't relevant or executable on a mobile device.

For example, in the past, the "insert image" button in the markdown editor, and the "choose file" button on the chat sidebar couldn't function on most mobile devices, as they lacked the ability to upload files from a browser.

**But now, Safari in iOS 6 treats "upload file" buttons on sites the same as the app element that allows a user to select an image from the phone to upload or edit.**

There's still no real file browser, so you can't upload anything else, so mobile Safari just treats "pick a file to upload" as "pick an image to upload." As such, it's now possible to do things like upload images into chat, but you have to navigate to the "full site" version and deal with the weird rendering and whatnot.

Is it worthwhile for us to add that element to the mobile versions of chat and the question edit window?

Comment: I would find this useful on Android (IIRC, it just uses the normal file picker, but that's better than nothing).

Comment: For what it's worth, I've had to transfer files from my phone a number of times to work around this. At the same time though, I usually quickly resize the images on the computer before uploading due to their dimensions. I suppose I could do that on my phone before uploading though, so this would still be a net win.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing.

Comment: [It happens](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/155498/mid-edit-change-notification-doesnt-clear-dirty-flag#comment446818_155498), heh.