# Is there a way to save an edit ? Or be advised that the post we are editing is already being edited?

Tags: feature-request, review, edits

The reason I am asking is the following : I recently started to edit a very long post, correcting the formatting for the code, making the question clearer, added tags, and when I was finished, pressing the Save Edits button, I received the following message :

> Another edit is awaiting approval for this post. Further edits cannot
>   be submitted until the pending edit is reviewed.

While I understand it can be quite a mess to have several pending edit for the same post, I could have saved 10 minutes if there had been some kind of visual indicator that someone else had saved an edit for the same question, not just a message when that edit is approved by a reviewer ...

Am I missing something here ? Could I save my edit somewhere while waiting to see if the first pending edit is satisfactory (or do I just have to leave my browser page open until the other edit is reviewed) ?

Comment: +1, probably edit button should be disabled, if it have another edit queue.

Comment: The edit button is disabled when there is another edit pending.  But when 2 people click edit at about the same time, things get messy.  The only way to do it now is to copy and past your edit, and wait for the other edit to get approved (or rejected) and then try again.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138543/discard-edit-confirmation-even-when-editing-has-been-stopped